# How do I let Google App Engine have a download link that downloads something from a database?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, download

Okay, let's say I have a database

```
Class Content(db.Model):
    code=db.TextProperty()
```

And I wanted to supply a download link on the webpage that would download the content of `code`. How would I do this?

I am using python and jinja2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd create a view that sends back the content of `code` (assuming that you're using the "webapp" framework):

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        content = Content.get(…)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
        self.response.out.write(content.code)
```

Note that you might want to set the `Content-Type` to something more specific. Also, if you want to force the browser to download the file (instead of possibly displaying the file), you can set the `Content-Disposition` header: `headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=some_filename.txt'`.